# SQL Server: WHERE, CASE, IN usage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck here. Can any one please help on the below scenario?
I am unable to use **IN** below, is there any other way to do?

```
DECLARE @Search_type INT = NULL --can be 1/2
        @search_value INT = NULL --its an id

SELECT * FROM r_table r
WHERE
(
    -- other conditions
)
AND
(
    r.id IN
    CASE @Search_type
        WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT e.r_id FROM e_table e WHERE @search_value = e.id)
        WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT e.r_id FROM e_table e WHERE @search_value = e.b_id)
    END
)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you're trying to do, the expected outcome and what happens when you use your current code?

Comment: What is the output? What is the expected output?

Comment: @PHeiberg 
In first where case condition i can directly compare it to the table's id against search_value
In second case condition i have to compare the table's id against a list of ids'am going to get from a select statement

Answer (score 2):

`Case` expressions only deal with scalars. The only query one can use is one that returns a scalar. (One row, one column.) Also another answer will not work because `case` does not work on Booleans.

However in this case the query can be transformed to:

```
SELECT * FROM r_table r
WHERE
(
    -- other conditions
)
AND
(
    r.id IN (SELECT e.r_id 
        FROM e_table e 
        WHERE @search_value 
            = CASE @Search_type 
                WHEN 1 THEN e.id
                WHEN 2 THEN e.b_id
                ELSE NULL END
    )
)
```

Comment: This worked like charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the simplest way to do it, but something like this ought to work:

```
AND (
    @Search_type = 1 AND EXISTS (
        SELECT e.r_id FROM e_table e WHERE @search_value = e.id AND e.r_id = r.id)
    OR
    @Search_type = 2 AND EXISTS (
        SELECT e.r_id FROM e_table e WHERE @search_value = e.b_id AND e.r_id = r.id)
)
```

[See SQL fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b3db/4)

Comment: In order to simple say. The case statement should work in this way.


IF(search_type = 1)

      r.id IN (SELECT e.r_id FROM e_table e WHERE search_value = e.id)

ELSE IF (search_type = 2)

      r.id IN (SELECT e.r_id FROM e_table e WHERE search_value = e.b_id)

I hope this help you understand the logic clearly

Comment: Isn't that what my statement does? Give example of input data and expected output in order for us to be able to understand you better in case my solution isn't correct. Use the SQL fiddle I linked to try it out.